# Send facebook private message as facebook email

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm implementing the feature of sending message in my native iOS app. I do a research and it seems that there is no APIs to send a private message to a friend. However there are workarounds:

- Use Send dialog (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send). However, I donnot know how to apply this for iOS app. I read somewhere  that it needs to integrate Facebook Javascript SDK but I think there is no way for an iOS native app.

- Sending to a facebook email instead of sending messages, but as above, I cannot find out how to use.

It would be great if anyone can give a help. Thanks

Comment: Just a heads up, Facebook is about to change how the email functionality to forward the email to the user's on-file email address, rather than turning it into a Message: https://www.facebook.com/help/703286543026907

Comment: so the 2nd workaround won't be possible. Can u give help on the 1st option or do you have any suggestions?